# SQLite is locked when I attempt to getReadableDatabase() after creating it in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

In my android app I've got the below code creating my database. This works no problem, but directly after this code is executed I attempt to getReadableDatabase() and it says the database is locked throwing an exception

Do I need to close / destory anything here to keep it from being locked? Thank you!

//this is done to see if it's created yet

```
private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = "/data/data/com.hats.android/databases/";
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            //database does't exist yet.
        }

        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }
```

//then the below is done to create it (following this is the getReadableDatabase() error)

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
            String myPath = "/data/data/com.hats.android/databases/";
            checkDB = this.myContext.openOrCreateDatabase(myPath, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
            checkDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE hats (hat_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, type TEXT)");
            checkDB.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onCreate() you should not need to do any of that. All you need is the execSQL line but instead of:

```
checkDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE hats (hat_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, type TEXT)");
```

simply use the passed in db:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE hats (hat_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, type TEXT)");
```

Comment: The param is actually a little off - i was passing in null. How can I init the database to exec SQL on it if it doesn't yet exist?

Comment: That param should never be null. Can you post the code for your constructor?

Comment: ahh it turns out I was calling this directly with a null arg, then right after I called the getReadableDatabase() method that called back into this same method ... huge fail on my part. Thanks for the clarity!